# How to set file's encode type using contentResolver?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using this code to call intent and set place where to create file in file explorer:

```
private val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()) { uri ->
        uri?.let { writeToFile(requireActivity(), it) }
    }

fun writeToFile(context: Context, source: Uri) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

        contentResolver.openOutputStream(source).use {
           out.write("id,Цвет,Размер\n".toByteArray())
           out.close()
        }
    }
```

But my CSV file have bad encode format so i'm getting unreadable text opening it on MS Office default app on my device. How can i set something like 1251 or Unicode to created file?

So "id" is ok and "Цвет", "Размер" looks broken and unreadable

Comment: De file wil be created by ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. The file is empty. Has 0 bytes. It has no encoding or BOM. Your app will write the bytes in the file. Your app will make it the file it wants. What goes wrong exactly? Android has a default encoding.

Comment: @blackapps main problem is encode type. It's UTF-8 as default i guess but i have unreadable text in MS Office on it. I need CP1251 or Unicode. Can you help me with it?

Comment: UTF-8 is also Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using writeLine() for your strings you should write bytes.

Something like:

```
String line = "this,is,a,csv,line\n";

stream.write(line.getBytes("1251"));
```

Sorry, forgot the right encoding.. Why didnt you mention it?

You also did not tell if ms office expects a bom.

Comment: I can't use .getBytes() method for string i don't have it. I'm user .toByteArray before but there is no result

Comment: I think MS Office expects a BOM. I did not use it before

Comment: Please post your relevant writing code in your post. We dont know what you do so it is difficult helping. And writing a BOM first is easy.

Comment: ok sorry. i will post how i handle it right now

Comment: And look for the right "1251" encoding parameter.

Comment: `out.write("id,Цвет,Размер\n".toByteArray())` Isn't `out.write("id,Цвет,Размер\n".toByteArray("1251"))` possible? Or Otherwise getBytes() ?

Comment: I used `.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_16))`. It's working fine with my language. But your answer is still reliable ty :)